# Linq To SQl Max

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a simple table containing 3 columsn

```
Id, Version, RecId.
 1,       1,    50
 1,       2,    51
 1,       3,    52
 2,       1,    53
 2,       2,    54
 3,       1,    55
```

I want to create a LINQ to SQL statement returning id and highest version.

So in this example my LINQ statement should return.
1,3
2,2
3,1

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a Give Me eTh Codes site.

Comment: Just like with SQL, first Group By the ID, then use a SELECT that contains a MAX aggregate

Comment: I tried writing in the code editor, in VS, but was confused how to specify the max statement, thought a forum was for asking :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and `Max`:

```
var query = db.TableName.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(g => new{ Id = g.Key, MaxVersion = g.Max(x => x.Version) });
```

Of course you could also create a collection of the poco class instead of this anonymous type. Or you could loop it in a `foreach`:

```
foreach(var x in query)
{
    int id = x.Id;
    int maxVersion = x.MaxVersion;
}
```

Comment: How to i loop through the query ?

Comment: @JesGudiksen: normally you use a `foreach`. I've edited my answer

Comment: Thx alot, was really helpfull :)